# how to modify array in javascript and pull random value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to build a simple quiz app for geography class, my logic is this: store the question into an array and pull a random question from an array, when the user clicks on the answer a function fires up and compare the answer, after answer exclude question from the array and pull another random question
so far I've managed to pull random question, give an answer, compare answer, and remove the question from the array and pull another random question but when function fires up the answer is compared with the first random question

here is y code so far:

```
    let judet = judete[Math.floor(Math.random() * judete.length)];

    console.log("start> "+judet);

    function checkAnswer(val){

        console.log("ras= "+val)


        if(val==judet){
            console.log("corect");


            let valueToRemove = val;
            let filteredItems = judete.filter(item => item !== valueToRemove);
            let judet = judete[Math.floor(Math.random() * judete.length)];

            console.log("inrebare= "+judet);

        }else{
            console.log("gresit");

            let valueToRemove = val;
            let filteredItems = judete.filter(item => item !== valueToRemove);
            let judet = judete[Math.floor(Math.random() * judete.length)];

            console.log("inrebare= "+judet);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Why not just shuffle and pop?

Comment: The problem is that you're re-declaring the variable `judet`, instead of `let judet = ..` use just `judet = ..`.

Comment: indeed, but now this raise another problem, i get duplicate questions, that means it did not remove question from the array. From my code above, after 3 answers the array should be empty, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dave said in the comments, you can shuffle the array and then pop.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  shuffle(arr);
  console.log(arr.pop());
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}
```

```html
Keep re-running me to see the result.
```

Comment: and where does my function for checking answers fit in?

Comment: @btz, This is a sample code, for your purpose I think you can do continue the same way you are asking questions but when there is a correct answer call `shuffle(arr);` then `var question = arr.pop();` to get the next question until the array has no more questions inside you can check easily with an if-statement.

Comment: `arr.pop();` function will remove one element in the array and give it to you, so you won't worry about repeating questions. You can see this in action in my snippet above.

Comment: i saw your snippet and i dont think is what i need or i dont know how to use it, your snippet put all the variable into console.log in different order, i need a single variable to compare it with the answer

Answer (score 0):

@Saud you pointed me into the right direction, here is how i have done it:

```
let judete = ["ar","ab","ag","tm","bh"];

    shuffle(judete);


    function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
     }
    }
        let judet = judete.pop();


    console.log("start> "+judet);  

    function checkAnswer(val){

        console.log("ras= "+val);


        if(val==judet){
            console.log("corect");

            shuffle(judete); 
            judet = judete.pop();

            console.log("inrebare= "+judet);

        }else{
            console.log("gresit");

            shuffle(judete); 
            judet = judete.pop();

            console.log("inrebare= "+judet);

        }


    }
```

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com)?

```
var arr = randoSequence(["question 1", "question 2", "question 3"]);
for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  console.log(arr.pop().value);
}
```

Just include this in your head tag if you wanna use my answer:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: same type of algorithm and same order of efficiency. less code.

Comment: and it also lets you grab the original index of the question by saying .index instead of .value if you end up needing that for some reason